# Unable to resolve/get the JWT token while running the JMETER script

Tags: jmeter, http-headers, jwt

I am trying to run a Jmeter test which runs a few calls and the the last POST call needs a JWT token.
I have captured both the Auth Token and there is an additional id_token but I am getting the following error.

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to Decode Token: policy(InbuildDecodeJWT)","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.jwt.FailedToDecode"}}}
```

I also noticed that the second to last calls delivers the x-Authorization header as a response header but I am unable to use it with the next call . Is there anyway where I can handle the JWT token without error? Will do a screenshare as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your logic of capturing the header is incorrect (either there is no match or the JWT token is incomplete or there are extra characters in there)

Just get the captured token value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination and paste it to the **Debugger** section of the [jwt.io website](https://jwt.io/), if everything goes well you should see the properly decoded token, if not - your [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) fails somewhere somehow